# Should you use openssl as command line or compile the library into the programming project?

Tags: c++, c, command-line, openssl

So you can compile openssl into you C++ project for example, and make everything as a single .exe file. Is this the correct way to do it?

Or should we instead just copy and paste openssl.exe command line utility into the exe location of our program and instead in our program call the openssl commands? Example("openssl enc -aes-cbc-256.....")

Im working on a bigger project and don't want to make this newbie mistake. I see for example NordVpn has in it's install location openssl.exe that seems to not be compiled into their .exe?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of project you are doing. You would dynamically or statically link openssl (you can read about the advantages/disadvantages everywhere). Please consider to use a different library, something that is easier to use. I would recommend https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/. In my opinion it is better for beginners.
If you have security concerns, read this: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/94629

Comment: I wouldn't speak of 'dynamic linking' in case of calling external executables. Usually you link dynamically against a DLL (or SO on linux) – a third option not mentioned in question...

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is secure encryption/decryption of data in your application, I'd strongly recommend 1) compiling your own OpenSSL libraries (or whichever encryption library you choose), and 2) static linking them into your application.

A call out to an external tool is much less secure. And you can't even be sure that the external tool binary your app calls will be the same one you originally distributed.